# elisp newbie question: Can't find 'filename' function definition in org.el?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I really love org-mode in emacs and want to customize a few things. While reading thru org.el, I'm finding several references to `filename` but can't find `filename` using `describe-function`?

I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I'm just learning elisp and it's not obvious. Any insight into where `filename` is defined? And/or if it's not a function, what is it?

For example, `filename` on line 25502:

```
         (filename (if to-buffer 
         (expand-file-name
          (concat
           (file-name-sans-extension
        (or (and subtree-p
             (org-entry-get (region-beginning)
                    "EXPORT_FILE_NAME" t))
            (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
           "." html-extension)
          (file-name-as-directory
           (or pub-dir (org-export-directory :html opt-plist))))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a function, that's a local variable created by the `let` special form.

**Note**: This is, of course, a wild guess since I cannot find the code you posted in the versions of `org.el` I can find, and none of them are even close to 25502 lines long.

Comment: Doh! you're right. I knew it was something simple-stupid. It's a giant let special form. Thanks.